# Strange compiler error for EF5 decimal type mapping

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, compiler-errors, entity-framework-5

My Class Library project references the Entity Framework 5 assembly. The .NET type for "AvailablePoints" in the code below is Decimal. I am trying to use CodeFirst Fluent API configurations to map this property to the decimal(9,4) data type in SQL Server so that data entries are not truncated at 2 decimal places, which is the default mapping.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<EventGroup>().Property(g => g.AvailablePoints).HasPrecision(9,4);
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

I get the following compiler error:

> "The type 'System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

If I remove `.Property(g => g.AvailablePoints).HasPrecision(9,4);` from the first statement in the method, it compiles fine. None of the EF5 documentation or forum posts address this compiler error or explain how this Fluent API configuration is related to the `System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography` type.

Comment: are you sure if you have the dll of Entity Framework in your project? Can you post your propriet? You did your FLuent API configuration in the same class of the model?

Comment: EntityFramework is a bit confusing:
1. There is the core of EntityFramework in System.Data.Entity (part of .net 4 and 4.5)
2. There is the code first stuff in assembly EntiyFramework.dll. This assembly depends on EntityFramework.dll. The class DbContext for example is in there.

Comment: Wow, that is confusing. All of the documentation, books, and training videos I have read makes it sound like everything you need comes along with the NuGet EF package. Apparently not. Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your project is not referencing a needed assembly.

In the Solution Explorer, find the "References" folder within your project.
Right-click that folder and click "Add Reference".
In the ".NET" tab, you can find the "System.Data.Entity" entry with the Version 4.0.0.0. Adding that *should* fix this issue.

Comment: In that case he can to use the parckage manager, because the Geograph datas of Sql Server run in the EF 5. PM is better because take the version too

Comment: The code compiled when I added the System.Data.Entity v4.0.0.0 reference, as suggested above. I guess that brought in the part of System.Data.Entity that is not included in EntityFramework.dll. @MayogaX - How would I have done the same thing via the package manager? I has already used the package manager to get the EF5 package, but that wasn't enough to resolve the issue.

Comment: Glad I found this.  It fixed me right up too.  Now, why on earth would we need an "older" assembly?